# Passing var from flask to html TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I keep getting an error saying:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'.
```

I've tried changing `{{session['guess']}}` double brackets to single brackets and without any brackets and neither works.

I also tried using `{{game}}` and that is also not working.

```
{% if {{session['guess']}} == {{session['game_num']}} %}
    <p>YOU WIN!</p>
{% elif {{session['guess']}} > {{session['game_num']}} %}
    <p>TOO HIGH</p>
{% elif {{session['guess']}} < {{session['game_num']}} %}
    <p>TOO LOW</p>
{% endif %}
```

Please help!

Comment: `{% if session['guess'] == session['game_num'] %}`

Comment: thank you, that fixed the error, however the comparison doesn't work :(

Comment: check your variable. try `{{ session["guess"] }}` without `if` block to print this variable and others.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use {{ or }} inside a python block instead use {% %} to access values.
{% %} should always contain plain python code. Use jinja2 online editor [here](http://jinja2test.tk/)

```
 {% if session['guess'] == session['game_num'] %}
       <p>YOU WIN!</p>
 {% elif session['guess'] > session['game_num'] %}
       <p>TOO HIGH</p>
 {% elif session['guess'] < session['game_num'] %}
       <p>TOO LOW</p>
 {% endif %}
```